# input axis vertical is not set up (C#) in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, input, axis

I'm trying to implement a player movement script but whenever I run the project it just displays the error "ArgumentException: Input Axis Verticle is not setup. To change the input settings use: Edit -> Settings -> Input PlayerMovement.Update () (at Assets/PlayerMovement.cs:14)"

I tried going into input controls and 'setting up the verticle axis' but to be honest I have no clue how. Also, I'm not sure is it is supposed to be like this, but when I change the verticle axis in the input settings to the y-axis it automatically changes the horizontal-axis to 'y' as well. here is my code in case it is needed but it did not display any errors

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Verticle");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

also, I am using C# in Unity.

Thanks in advance!
B.G

Comment: Because that’s not how you spell it. You could look up in the setup of input to check how it’s spelt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float z = Input.GetAxis("Verticle");
```

change to

```
float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

detailed instructions on changing input in future : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html